# extract arguments from deep link

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, deep-linking

I'm using a deep link navigation component and I'm facing a simple issue, this is my code

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/dest_screen"
    android:name="ScreenF"
    android:label=""
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_screen">

    <deepLink app:uri="host.com/category/{xyz}" />

    <deepLink app:uri="host.com/category/{xyz}/{abc}" />

    <argument
        android:name="xyz"
        android:defaultValue="@null"
        app:argType="string"
        app:nullable="true" />
   
    <argument
        android:name="abc"
        android:defaultValue="@null"
        app:argType="string"
        app:nullable="true" />
    
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_dest_xxx"
        app:destination="@id/dest_xxx" />

</fragment>
```

if the deep link is :

> host.com/category/{xyz}/{abc}?key=1

I'm receiving the params correctly for `xyz` & `abc` in the SafeArgs but, if the URL is

> host.com/category/{xyz}?key=1

I'm receiving the wrong value for `xyz` and I find the `abc` has to a value too even the pattern is not achieved of second deep link

> host.com/category/real_xyz/real_abc?key=1&sort=2

the value for `xyz` is taking part of string for real_abc+ rest of usrl
xyz = l_abc?key=1&sort=2

while for `abc` it's taking the full path after category
abc = real_xyz/real_abc?key=1&sort=2

> as a note: if I removed host.com/{xyz}/{abc} deep link everything is working for the issue i posted

my question here is why `abc` having value if the URL not have /real_abc

so, I'm struggling here, can anyone tell me please what. am I missing?

Comment: Can you post a concrete example of the URL you use for testing and what the wrong value for `xyz` and `abc` is in this case?

Comment: updated, can you check please?

Comment: As both `deepLink`s point to the same fragment, you could probably remove one and then do the parsing of the URI (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri) yourself in the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the deep links should be implicit and unique.
Just write a complete deep link instead of writing in different forms.

this one should be enough:

```
<deepLink app:uri="host.com/category/{xyz}/{abc}" />
```

remove this one:

```
<deepLink app:uri="host.com/category/{xyz}" />
```

Comment: what will happen when my URL does not have `abc` part? e.x:  `host.com/category/{xyz}?sort=2&type=asd'. can you tell me what would be happen here?

Comment: hello? any update please?